# Is it mandatory to mention protocol to load jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

Below code,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log(jQuery);
</script>
```

---

works fine in firefox browser **after** `src` is modified to `"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"`(remote file) or `"../js/jquery.min.js"`(local file)

Otherwise, dev console gives `Reference error: jQuery is not defined`

I would like to test the code with remote library but not local

How do I understand this problem?

Comment: Any errors in console? Is your website running on a machine or using `file` protocol (`file:///`) or under `https` schema?

Comment: which one is the FF version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Mosh Feu, if you run a file locally, without a webserver, you cannot use protocol relative paths to load jQuery. That's because it is trying to find a local reference: `file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js`.

Well, you could if you have jQuery locally in a folder `/some/where/jQuery.js` and you reference it with `<script src="//some/where/jQuery.js>`

So yes, if you're running pages from the disk directly, you must specify the protocol if you want jQuery from a CDN. See the first comment on http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Save yourself some trouble, install a local web server.

Answer (score 2):

Leaving the scheme off the URL means that it is scheme relative.

If the HTML document is loaded over HTTP then the JS will be too.

If the HTML document is loaded over HTTPS then the JS will be too.

If the HTML document is loaded over FILE then … the JS won't be because `file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js` doesn't exist.

Do your local testing on a local web server, don't load your HTML directly from your file system.

Answer (score 0):

You must be viewing the file locally without using a web server which results in a wrong URL when the protocol is not explicitly specified.